# Hibernate aggregating

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

Is it possible to get as a result from hibernate directly this...

```
List<Map<Sth, List<SthLog> list;
```

when classes are mapped in such a way (not bidirectional)?:

```
@Entity
public class SthLog {

        @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Sth sth; }
```

I know that this maybe seems to be a silly question, because normally you can add bidirectional mapping, but in this case I can change entities definition and I wonder if I can get required structure directly from hibernate.

Comment: I can imagine what a `List<SthLog>` would contain (all the SthLog). I can also imagine what a `Map<Sth, List<SthLog>>`  would contain(all the SthLog, indexed by their Sth). But what would a `List<Map<Sth, List<SthLog>>>` contain?

Comment: hmmm... actually I really need something like Map<Sth, List<SthLog> but... as I understand hibernate it always returns a list as a result, so getting something like List<Map<Sth, List<SthLog>>> would be for me(api side) and for the client acceptable. So List<Map<Sth, List<SthLog>>> would contain a list of single-element Maps in which key is Sth, and value its List<SthLog>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't expect Hibernate to do everything for you. Transforming a List into a Map (or a Guava Multimap, which is easier and more appropriate here) is a matter of 3 lines of codes:

```
// get all the SthLog with their sth
List<SthLog> list = 
    session.createQuery("select s from SthLog s inner join fetch s.sth").list();
// index them by their sth
ListMultimap<Sth, SthLog> result = ArrayListMultimap.create();
for (SthLog sthLog : list) {
    result.put(sthLog.getSth(), sthLog);
}
```

Comment: yeah, that is of course true that there is not too much lines of code, but what about efficiency in such solutions, like rewriting one container into antother if you have many records? Im asking just theoretically according to your expierence, because maybe in this concrete issue would be better to convince entity designer to do bi-directional mappings. Kind regards.

Comment: Hibernate would have to do the same thing. You could iterate() or scroll() instead of list(), but I don't think it would change much. Creating a map from a list is many orders of magnitude faster than executing a SQL query returning a large amount of data from an external database, which could even be on a different machine.

Comment: Yes but drilling it down, isn't hibernate caching fetched results somehow and hereby it could be faster to have complete container somewhere in a cache?! (this is read-only table) instead of fetching results from db. I don't know this probably needs to make a specific test for this case. Anyway thank for your help.

Comment: Hibernate caches entities in its first level cache. The way you get entities doesn't matter. It doesn't cache results of queries.